# rake db structure load Heroku

Tags: heroku

setup is Heroku Cedar, RDS postgres, rails4

expected `heroku run rake db:structure:load` to create tables but no tables were created. It probably didn't execute a line from db/structure.sql

Is this the correct behavior?

As a work around, revert to psql directly into RDS.